# htaccess RewriteCond only if specific parameters exist

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters, query-string

I am using these 4 lines in my htaccess file to both redirect and rewrite a URL:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /GetSearch1-test\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Class=Residential\&Neighborhood\%5B\%5D=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /Neighborhoods/%1\.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^Neighborhoods/([^.]*)\.html$ /GetSearch1-test.php?Class=Residential\&Neighborhood\%5B\%5D=$1 [NC,L]
```

It will take this URL:
    www.domain.com/GetSearch1-test.php?Class=Residential&Neighborhood%5B%5D=Wailea
and redirect it to this URL:
    www.domain.com/Neighborhoods/Wailea.html

It works, but with major issues. Problem is, I only want it to do the redirect if only those two parameters exist (Class & Neighborhood).  The first parameter is fixed, but the second one could be anything. If I add a third parameter to the URL, it still redirects and I don't want it to.

For example, if I go to this URL:
    www.domain.com/GetSearch1-test.php?Class=Residential&Neighborhood%5B%5D=Wailea&Parameter3=whatever

It still redirects. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change 2nd RewriteCond with that:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Class=Residential&Neighborhood\%5B\%5D=([^&]*)$ [NC]
```

Comment: It works!.  Thank you very much.  I have no idea why, but it does.  I will research what this is: [^&]  Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. `[^&]` means "Any character which is not `&`". Thank you to "accept" my answer...

Comment: You may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer. thanks !